# parallax scroll effect getting laggy

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

i wrote a script that basically gives the topper element a negative margin bottom,
so it makes the element below it go up and it kind of makes a parallax like scroll, my problem is i wrote the function as a scroll and i think the function runs so much that it makes the page kind of laggy, here`s my code, i hope you guys can help me out.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if (scrollY >= 100) {
        $("#gallery").css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY - 100) / 4));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you are re-querying the DOM every time the scroll event fires. I would start by caching the selector outside of the event handler.

```
var $gallery = $("#gallery");
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if (scrollY >= 100) {
    $gallery.css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY - 100) / 4));
  }
});
```

You then might want to play around with wrapping your DOM manipulations in a setTimeout.

```
var $gallery = $("#gallery");
var delay;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  delay = setTimeout(function() {
    if (scrollY >= 100) {
      $gallery.css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY - 100) / 4));
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

EDIT: 
For detecting scroll direction, try something like:

```
var $gallery = $("#gallery");
var delay;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  delay = setTimeout(function() {

    if (scrollPos > lastScrollTop){
      if (scrollY >= 100) {
        $gallery.css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY - 100) / 4));
      }
    } else {
      if (scrollY < 100) {
        $gallery.css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY + 100) / 4));
      }
    }

  }, 50);
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: thanks, but another major problem that i am facing is when i scroll up till the end of the page and suddenly scroll up again to the top, it doesn't seem to work, i mean it freezes and after u scroll it again a bit it starts working, do u have any suggestion on how can i fix it or another way to achieve this kind of scrolling effect?

Comment: I made an edit. I'm not able to test this. Consider adding a run-able snippet, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The lag you experience is due to two main factors.

1. There are a huge number of Scroll events fired when a page is
   scrolled
2. Javascript implementations are primarily single
   threaded.

**What can we do two fix these problems?**

To fix the first issue, you can either `debounce` or `throttle` the `onscroll` callback function. Here is a [simple but good write](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/) up about these techniques.

To fix the second problem, is to give that single thread time to do other tasks as well. If you endup using `debounce` or `throttle`, it should help or you can rely on browsers eventloop.

Basically, the idea is to tell the browser that `Hey, this is something I want you to do, but take your time`. The simplest ways to do that is by using `setTimeout` webapi.

Rewriting your implementation,

```
var gallery = $("#gallery");
var scrollHandler = function() {
  if (scrollY >= 100) {
    gallery.css("margin-bottom", -((scrollY - 100) / 4));
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  setTimeout(scrollHandler, 4)
});
```